# filesize para arquivos maiores que 2GB em plataformas x86

Tags: php, sistema-de-arquivos, inteiros

Estava a ler a documentação do PHP e notei esta informação:

> Note: Because PHP's integer type is signed and many platforms use 32bit integers, some filesystem functions may return unexpected results for files which are larger than 2GB.

Ao acessar a documentação em Português notei isto:

> Nota: Como o tipo inteiro do PHP é sinalizado e muitas plataformas utilizam inteiros de 32 bits, filesize() pode retornar resultados inesperados para arquivos que sejam maiores que 2 Gb. Para arquivos entre 2 Gb e 4 Gb você pode resolver esse problema utilizando sprintf("%u", filesize($file)).

Eles passam uma dica do uso do `sprintf`, no entanto encontrei esta pergunta:

- [PHP x86 How to get filesize of >2GB file without external program?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5501451/1518921) (até construíram uma classe pro tal serviço https://github.com/jkuchar/BigFileTools)

Aparentemente eles tentaram vários métodos. Eu não sei se foi algum colaborador da documentação em Português que adicionou este código:

```
sprintf("%u", filesize($file))
```

O que eu gostaria de saber é se ele tem algum problema (já que parece que apenas o pessoal da documentação em Português pensou nisto). Por exemplo:

- Ele falha em alguma determinada situação?
- Ele não tem precisão quanto ao peso real do arquivo?
- Ou o código realmente funciona pra converter o peso em inteiros pra um string numérica?

Comment: O problema de se utilizar cURL é se o arquivo tiver 4gb o servidor demora consciencialmente

Comment: @FABIOMATEUS mesmo definindo o `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, 1);` ele demora? Se for demorado ainda sim, então use a primeira solução, com `stat -c` e `for %F in` que demonstrei em https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/183202/3635

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Parece que o problema se estende além e apesar do relato do Edilson, notei que não é em todo ambiente ou versão do PHP que isto irá funcionar bem e nem de maneira necessariamente precisa.

Em um sistema x64 um arquivo maior que 4GB retornou um valor positivo, mas não era o tamanho do arquivo, ou seja isso **não funcionou**:

```
 sprintf("%u", filesize($file))
```

Mesmo estando em um ambiente x64 e o PHP5 sendo compilado para x64, ainda não será 100% x64, na verdade ele é x86_x64 em **Windows** (no PHP7 as coisas funcionaram um pouco melhor).

O problema não é bem com PHP necessariamente, mas é devido ao PHP5 trabalhar com 32bit e mesmo o 64bit terá uma limitação, então o que eu precisava era de algo que funcione bem quase que independente do ambiente, não preciso necessário fazer calculos com o valor, eu só precisava saber o tamanho de um arquivo, cheguei a estas soluções:

### Softwares nativos do sistema

Está solução vai depender do [`stat`](https://linux.die.net/man/2/stat) estar disponível em servidores Linux e Mac OSX e BSD por exemplo, eu não sei afirmar se é algo que funciona em todas plataformas, para Windows usei isto [*SOen*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5502328/1518921)

Algo como:

- Unix-like: `stat -c %s arquivopesado.7z` (existem variações deste comando para diferentes tipos de sistemas *unix-like*, inclusive para Mac, ou seja teria que ajustar o comando)
- Windows: `for %F in ("arquivopesado.7z") do @echo %~zF`

O script ficou assim:

```php
<?php
function filesizealternativo($arquivo)
{
    if (is_file($arquivo) === false) {
        return false;
    }

    $arqarg = escapeshellarg(realpath($arquivo));

    if (strcasecmp(substr(PHP_OS, 0, 3), 'WIN') === 0) {
        $command = 'for %F in (' . $arqarg . ') do @echo %~zF';
    } else {
        $command = 'stat -c %s ' . $arqarg;
    }

    $resposta = shell_exec($command);

    if ($resposta === null) {
        return false;
    }

    $resposta = trim($resposta);

    if (is_numeric($resposta)) {
        return $resposta;
    }

    return false;
}

$a = filesizealternativo('arquivogrande.7z');

var_dump($a);
```

### Usando o protocolo file:/// com PHP

O problema de usar `stat` é a compatibilidade de alguns servidores e dependências, também existem alguns servidores que bloqueiam as funções `shell_exec`, `exec`, `system`, etc, então efetuei um teste com CURL e `file://` (http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.file.php), o resultado foi bem funcional:

```
function filesizealternativo2($arquivo)
{
    if (is_file($arquivo) === false) {
        return false;
    }

    $arquivo = realpath(preg_replace('#^file:#', '', $arquivo));

    $ch = curl_init('file://' . ltrim($arquivo, '/'));

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); //Faz o retorno ser salvo na variável
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1); //Faz retornar os headers
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, 1); //Evita retornar o corpo

    $headers = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    $ch = null;

    //Com preg_match extraímos o tamanho retornado de Content-Length
    if (preg_match('#(^c|\sc)ontent\-length:(\s|)(\d+)#i', $headers, $matches) > 0) {
        return $matches[3];
    }

    return false;
}

$a = filesizealternativo2('arquivogrande.7z');

var_dump($a);
```

Desta maneira a única dependência será a extensão Curl, o que geralmente já é habilitado em muitos servidores.

Answer (score 7):

Parece que, o problema ocorre devido a sinalização que o próprio *PHP* impõe aos do tipo *inteiro*, e muitas plataformas utilizam sinalizações de *32 bits*, razão pela qual o *filesize()* ás vezes retorna resultados inesperados para arquivos maiores que *2GB*.

Quanto a explicação acerca do porquê essa expressão é mais indicada, é um bocado complicado responder, visto que vários usuários tentaram de várias formas escrever métodos próprios e até mais complexos, para obter o tamanho real de um arquivo.

> It prints the result of filesize as UNSIGNED INT so it can be until 4GB.
>   The reason is, SIGNED INT runs until 2GB and flips to -2GB watch following:
>
> **Tradução:**
>   Isto imprime o resultado de _"filesize" como *"inteiro não assinado"*, por isso pode ser até 4GB. Acontece porque, *"inteiros assinados"* são executados até os 2GB e vira para -2GB, veja:

```
file<2GB      = SIGNED:  1048576512 UNSIGNED: 1048576512
file>2GB      = SIGNED: -2100140103 UNSIGNED: 2194827193
file>4GB      = SIGNED:  -100662784 UNSIGNED: 4194304512
```

Esta texto citado acima foi retirado de um diretório qualquer do *PHP*, nele o usuário explica porquê da função. Porém não diz se é a mais indicada ou não.

Ao meu ver, é bem provável que esta expressão está a ser usada, porque ela retorna valores negativos para arquivos entre *2GB e 4GB*, que podem ainda ser corrigidos com algum cálculo, e retorna um valor a título definitivo e incorrigível para ficheiros acima de *4GB*. De facto foi é meio alarmante o exemplo estar apenas na nota da documentação em português, mas, o exemplo já existia nas notas de contribuição.

Na página do *PHP* normalmente os exemplos que lá encontramos são os mais simples, isso não significa que seja a única maneira de obter o tamanho real de um arquivo. É bem provável que isso exija alguns testes da tua parte, porque não se encontra muita informação sobre o porquê do uso do *sprintf*.

> Ele falha em alguma determinada situação?

Alguns usuários relataram, que houve falhas nalguns sistemas baseados na arquitetura x86, e alguns problemas relatados em sistemas x64, por isso é bem provável que ainda haja alguns erros. Ainda se falhar, vai retornar um `E_WARNING` ou simplesmente `FALSE`.

> Ele não tem precisão quanto ao peso real do arquivo?

A precisão é boa, retorna o tamanho real em *bytes*.

> Ou o código realmente funciona pra converter o peso em inteiros pra um string numérica?

Sim, funciona, foi este o retorno que obtive no último resultado:

```
$file = "ficheiro.zip";
var_dump(sprintf("%u", filesize($file)));

Retorno: string(4) "5209" (5.08KB)
Retorno: string(10) "2092964971" (1.94GB)
```

Existem vários exemplos disponíveis sobre como obter o tamanho real dos arquivos para as mais diversas plataformas, alguns até são com base no `shell`, basta que procures o que melhor se adapta a ti. Se precisares de mais detalhes, creio que  a única solução será fazeres testes isolados, e ir mais à fundo na busca.

Boa sorte.

---

## Referências:

[PHP.cz](http://students.kiv.zcu.cz/doc/php5/manual/en/function.filesize.php.html)

[PHP.tw](http://cct.me.ntut.edu.tw/ccteducation/chchting/aiahtm/computer/phphelp/function.filesize.php.htm)

[PHP.edu](http://titanic.fauser.edu/php/function.filesize.php.htm)

[Drupal.org](https://www.drupal.org/node/714224)

[PHP.net](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.filesize.php)

Comment: NB - em português do brasil se diz "inteiro com sinal" e "inteiro sem sinal",e não "assinado" e "não assinado" - como as palavras "assinado" exsitem para outro contexto, também como tradução de "signed" pode haver alguma confusão na sua tradução. (eu me confundi :-p)