# Forçar download com php arquivo vem corrompido

Tags: php, download

Olá, o código até chega a fazer download, o problema é que vem corrompido, e não tenho a minima ideia do por que isso acontece.

O download é chamado assim `site.com/download/key`

.htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule (.*) /index.php [QSA,L]
```

index.php

```
<?php
require 'config/Config.php';
require 'config/tratarUrl.php';
?>
<html lang="pt-br">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?=DIR_CSS?>Style.css">
    <link rel="icon" href="<?= DIR_IMAGES?>icon.png"
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Site</title>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php
            include $pag;
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

download.php

```
$file_path = DIR_ARQUIVOS.$key.'.zip';
$file_name = $key.'.zip';
$new_name = $sql->getKeyName($key);

set_time_limit(0);

// Verifica se o arquivo não existe
if (!file_exists($file_path)) {
// Exiba uma mensagem de erro caso ele não exista
exit;
}

// Configuramos os headers que serão enviados para o browser
header('Content-Type: "application/zip"');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.basename($file_path).'"');
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
header('Expires: 0');
header('Pragma: no-cache');
// Envia o arquivo para o cliente
readfile($file_name);
```

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/55977/discussion-between-guilherme-nascimento-and-lucas-carezia).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O problema todo é que você está fazendo o download junto do conteúdo do index.php:

```php
<?php
require 'config/Config.php';
require 'config/tratarUrl.php';
?>
<html lang="pt-br">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?=DIR_CSS?>Style.css">
    <link rel="icon" href="<?= DIR_IMAGES?>icon.png"
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Site</title>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php
            include $pag;
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Ou seja quando baixa o arquivo, isso está vindo junto:

```html
<html lang="pt-br">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Style.css">
    <link rel="icon" href="icon.png">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Site</title>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
    </head>
    <body>
        CONTEUDO DO ARQUIVO AQUI
    </body>
</html>
```

Eu recomendo separar o download.php ou simplesmente criar um if.

Usando if:

```php
<?php
require 'config/Config.php';
require 'config/tratarUrl.php';

if (preg_match('#pages/download\.php$#', $pag) > 0) {
     include $pag;
     exit;
}
?>
<html lang="pt-br">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?=DIR_CSS?>Style.css">
    <link rel="icon" href="<?= DIR_IMAGES?>icon.png"
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Site</title>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php
            include $pag;
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Ou então você pode reescrever o .htaccess assim:

```apache
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d

#se a url vier com prefix download
RewriteRule ^download/ /pages/download.php [QSA,L]

#outras urls
RewriteRule (.*) /index.php [QSA,L]
```

Então o seu `pages/download.php` deve ficar algo **mais ou menos** assim:

```
<?php
require 'config/Config.php';

//... Conteudo do seu download.php ...

$file_path = DIR_ARQUIVOS.$key.'.zip';
$file_name = $key.'.zip';
$new_name = $sql->getKeyName($key);

set_time_limit(0);

// Verifica se o arquivo não existe
if (!file_exists($file_path)) {
// Exiba uma mensagem de erro caso ele não exista
exit;
}

// Configuramos os headers que serão enviados para o browser
header('Content-Type: "application/zip"');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.basename($file_path).'"');
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
header('Expires: 0');
header('Pragma: no-cache');
// Envia o arquivo para o cliente
readfile($file_name);
```

### Problemas com `filesize`

O `filesize` não era o problema do teu script, mas sim o conteúdo misturado como citei, uma coisa interessante de enviar o `Content-Length` é que a barra de progresso dos navegadores costumar dar uma estimativa em porcentagem do download mais precisa, então seria interessante definir isto. Todavia é bom notar que `filesize` usa `int` e dependendo da arquitetura do processador você terá limites, o que pode ocasionar problemas como o que citei em *[filesize para arquivos maiores que 2GB em plataformas x86](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/91766/3635)*

Uma solução alternativa seria usando o `CURL` (que retorna em `string` e não em `int`), assim:

```php
function filesizecurl($arquivo)
{
    if (is_file($arquivo) === false) {
        return false;
    }

    $arquivo = realpath(preg_replace('#^file:#', '', $arquivo));

    $ch = curl_init('file://' . ltrim($arquivo, '/'));

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); //Faz o retorno ser salvo na variável
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1); //Faz retornar os headers
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, 1); //Evita retornar o corpo

    $headers = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    $ch = null;

    //Com preg_match extraímos o tamanho retornado de Content-Length
    if (preg_match('#(^c|\sc)ontent\-length:(\s|)(\d+)#i', $headers, $matches) > 0) {
        return $matches[3];
    }

    return false;
}

// Configuramos os headers que serão enviados para o browser
header('Content-Length: ' . filesizecurl($file_name));
header('Content-Type: "application/zip"');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.basename($file_path).'"');
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
header('Expires: 0');
header('Pragma: no-cache');
// Envia o arquivo para o cliente
readfile($file_name);
```

Answer (score 2):

Não sei se a sua situação é essa:

ao requisitar o download ao invés de abrir a janela "salvar como" aparece na tela uns caracteres extranhos tipo:

PK劦QJ曷.arquivo.htmarquivo zip de teste PK劦QJ曷. arquivo.htmPK9?

Se esse for o caso então você deve verificar se antes da tag de abertuta do php há espaços em branco, se houver retire-os de modo que a primeira linha seja `<?php` ou seja a linha 1 deve começar pela tag de abertura do php

> Onsiderações finais:

1. O envio de cabeçalhos HTTP deve ser realizados sempre antes de qualquer saída ao navegador, ou seja, sempre antes de códigos HTML e funções que exibam dados, como echo, print, print_r etc. Também não pode haver espaços vazios no código, antes da tag `<?php`.
2. Outro detalhe é o BOM. O BOM (Byte Order Mark, ou Marca de Ordem de Byte) é uma sequência de caracteres que é inserida no início de um arquivo para definir a ordem dos bytes. Isso é outra razão para esse problema.

Comment: Não fica com nenhum nome estranho, e o arquivo é baixado com o mesmo tamanho que foi feito upload, porem ele vem corrompido com a seguinte mensagem do WinRAR `Arquivo.zip. O arquivo está em formato desconhecido ou danificado.`.
Não tem nenhum espaço antes da tag `<php?` e nem antes da tag `?>`, o código que eu uso para forçar download esta no meio de outros códigos, não sei se isso tem problema ou precisa estão em uma classe sozinho.

Comment: Rapaz, que situação heim. Achei isso por ai  http://www.yodot.com/pt/zip-reparar/archive-e-tampouco-corromper-ou-danificado.html

Comment: Eu olhei, porem não achei nada, até por que eu uso o php para fazer a compactação, porem quando eu acabo de compactar com php e abro, o arquivo funciona perfeitamente, o problema é quando forço download.

Comment: Entendi, não vou remover, por enquanto, a minha resposta, para que outros da comunidade vejam esses comentários e possam entender melhor o seu problema.